# Where can I find Ubuntu images with different packages pre-installed?

Tags: system-installation, iso, hadoop

I'd like to get an image of the latest Ubuntu with Hadoop configured for a single node so that I don't have to do it myself.

Is there a public repository of Ubuntu images somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Cloudera Distribution for Hadoop 4 (CDH4) uses Ubuntu. CDH4 comes with Hadoop products pre-installed and configured for development. Some of the installed products are:

- Hadoop (HDFS and YARN/MapReduce)
- HBase
- Oozie
- Pig & Hive

You can get the VM and the instructions on how to use it from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v0zGBZ6EHap-Smsr3x3sGGpDW-54m82kDpPKC2M6uiY/edit#)

There is also a [Qucikstart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-4-x.html) for CDH 5.4.x but that runs on CentOS

See the following links for more info:

https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud617/l-308873795/m-313523874